# Square root of consecutive integers

Tags: c#, math, square-root

[image: This image is an exercise for our algorithm lab.]

Why do I receive an incorrect answer? This is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input a number for the formula: i.e. (1,5,9,13...)");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
double total = 0;
for (int i = n; i >=1; i=i-4)
{
    if (i == 1)
        total++;
    else
        total += Math.Sqrt(n);
}

Console.Write(total);
```

Comment: btw you can write i=i-4 as  i -= 4

Comment: Your code is just calculating sqrt(n) + sqrt(n) + ..; + sqrt(n) + 1

Comment: To get correct answer you need to work backwards starting with square root of 13 (seconds example 17).

Comment: @EtienneCharland Yeah, I know but when I exucuted the program and it gives me wrong answer; I am trying everything to correct that. Thanx btw

Comment: @AnotherProgrammer yeah I didn't realised that while studying thanx !

Comment: Today is a good day to learn how to find your own bugs.  Some good beginner advice is here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3):

For each integer `i`, the square root should be applied on the sum up to now, not just on the current `i`:

```
double total = 0;
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i-=4)
{
     total = Math.Sqrt(total + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're adding the square root of `n` every time. The value for `n` is assigned prior to your loop and never changes. You need to increment by the square root of `i + total` every time instead of the square root of `n`:

```
// My input for testing was 13.
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double total = 0;
for (int i = n; i > 1; i -=4)
    total = Math.Sqrt(total + i);

Console.WriteLine($"Total: {Math.Sqrt(++total)} = 1.980.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Feel free to look into the difference between [pre and post increment/decrement](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-operator-in-C++-What-is-the-difference-between-code-a++-code-and-code-++a-code-in-C++).

```
int i = 1;
int x = i++; //x is 1, i is 2
int y = ++i; //y is 3, i is 3
```

Comment: I think your answer is wrong too @Mureinik did correct, but you were right I forget to input i in the for loop, I just coded as for 'n' and its so wrong :) Thanx to you I realised one of more of my mistakes.